# Update the column based on matching values using shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

Consider a file A with data as

```
111 Apple Red 
112 Orange Orange
113 Mango Yellow
```

File B with data as

```
111 Apple Blue
112 Orange Black
```

Expected result should be file c as

```
111 Apple Blue 
112 Orange Black
113 Mango Yellow
```

I have tried with below code

```
#! /bin/ksh
cd /test/files
file1=`ls abc.dat`
file2=`ls cde.dat`
cat $file1 | while read line
do
  var1 =$18
  var2=$03
  cat $file2 | while read line
  do
     var3=$01
     var4=$02
     if [$var1==$var3];then
        mv -v "$file1" "$(echo $file1 | sed 's/$var2/$var4/g')"
     fi
   done
done
exit 0
```

but getting an errors while executing the scripts

Comment: I have tried with below code

Comment: #! /bin/ksh

cd /test/files

file1=`ls abc.dat`
file2=`ls cde.dat`

cat $file1 | while read line
do
var1 =$18
var2=$03
cat $file2 | while read line
do
var3=$01
var4=$02
if [$var1==$var3];then
mv -v "$file1" "$(echo $file1 | sed 's/$var2/$var4/g')"
fi
done
done
exit 0

Comment: but getting an errors while executing the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental issues in the code as comments:

```
#! /bin/ksh
cd /test/files
file1=`ls abc.dat` # Should be just file1=abc.dat
file2=`ls cde.dat` # Ditto
cat $file1 | while read line # Use More Quotes™ - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
do
  var1 =$18 # Syntax error - remove the space. Also, `$18` refers to the variable with the name `18`, which is not defined. Did you mean to write an awk script to get the 18th column?
  var2=$03
  cat $file2 | while read line
  do
     var3=$01
     var4=$02
     if [$var1==$var3];then # You must have spaces around `[` and `==` (which should be a single `=`) and before `]`
        mv -v "$file1" "$(echo $file1 | sed 's/$var2/$var4/g')"
     fi
   done
done
exit 0
```